# Using expo-speech in android doesn't work and throw exception

Tags: android, react-native, expo, text-to-speech

I am trying to use expo-speech in my react-native app and I am getting the following error on my Android:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Encountered an exception while calling native method: Exception occurred while executing exported method speak on module ExponentSpeech: null]
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\NativeModules.js:155:41 in createErrorFromErrorData
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\NativeModules.js:104:55 in <unknown>
- ... 5 more stack frames from framework internals
```

The code is the following:

```
speak = async text => {
  Speech.speak(convertHTMLstring(text), {
    language: 'he',
    pitch: '1',
    rate: '0.9',
  })
}
```

react-native: 0.59.8

Dependencies are the following:

```
"expo": "^35.0.0",
"expo-speech": "~7.0.0",
"react": "16.8.3",
...
```

Same code works in ios.

I tried to look for an answer but I couldn't find anything and according to expo docs, it should support Android:
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/speech/

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: Anyone has an idea to my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone who may it be relevant to him...
I found the problems.
First of all, note that I tried to use the speech for the Hebrew languge.
So:

1. Android doesn't have in default a TTS engine for Hebrew. I had to download it and install. I didn't find anything for free but I found one with a free 7 days trial:
   https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=es.codefactory.vocalizertts
2. the options pitch and rate in my code do not works (maybe because of this engine) and cause an exception!

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like this is a bare react-native project and not a managed expo project, is that correct? if so, be sure to set up react-native-unimodules in your project first: https://github.com/unimodules/react-native-unimodules

Comment: As far as I know it, I use a managed expo project but I am not 100% sure about that (sorry, pretty new with react-native and expo).  
I use expo API, actually also the text to speech package is imported from expo:
import * as Speech from 'expo-speech'  
So, how can I check it whether I use bare react-native project or a managed expo project?
And if I use the managed expo project, do you have an idea why I get this error?  
Thanks!